# Unexpected behaviour with OkHttp on Android Devices

Tags: java, android, random, okhttp, tls1.2

For research purposes I used OkHttp3 as a dependency in my android application and in my native java environment. These are two identical applications which do the same.

The idea is simple: I create an instance of the OkHttpClient Class and set the random number generator in the SocketFactoryClass. Here is an example:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(new CustomSSLSocketFactory(null), x509TrustManagers)
    .build();
```

The CustomSSLSocketFactory class creates a SSLContext and within this init()-Method the new random number generator is handed over. It's looking like this:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, rand);
```

`rand` is in this case my own random number generator.

---

Next I tested this code on my android mobile application and in my native java environment. For test purposes I set the random value to 0x41.

So when I looked at the data packets (send by my java program) I saw the random field filled with bytes of 0x41 (A). But when I tested this application on my android phone, the random value is not a block of 0x41 bytes. I don't understand this behaviour on android smartphones.

Can anyone of you tell me why I cannot set the random number generator in android applications.